# Python matching data in two files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

first of all, I am asking with the sample code in my hand under normal conditions, but I did not come up with the slightest solution for this issue.

I have two txts, the first txt:

```
French,01
Brasil,07
USA,23
England,34
Egypt,51
...
```

second txt

```
French
Paris
England
London
...
```

The first txt has more data than the second. My goal is to combine the data in the first txt according to what is in the second txt, for example:
**England,London,34**

So far, I've tried something by converting txts to lists with the map(),reduce(), startswith(),zip() methods, but they do the matching either sequentially or randomly. how can i solve this?

```
list1 = ['French','01', 'Brasil','07']
list2 = ['French','Paris','England','London']

zip(list1,list2) ->> [('French','French'), ('01', Paris)]
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *combine the data in the first txt according to what is in the second txt*?

Comment: Based on the two txts I gave in the question, I need the following output: England,London,34. I can either print them directly or combine them in a new txt, it doesn't matter as long as I can reach it.

Comment: It seems suited for dictionaries; run through one of them by keyword, and match to the other

Comment: What logic did you apply to conclude that "England,34" had to be combined with "London"? The fact that they're each on the fourth line, or something else you didn't spell out here?

Comment: Your first text has lines, with comma-separate fields, but your `list1` example collapses that to a flat list. Is that intentional? It might be better to parse it to a list of tuples, maybe?

Comment: Joanis, first of all thank you for the edit.each on the fourth line but it didn't work, do you have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: @ALT Does my answer help?

Comment: there is a mapping but it is not working correctly :/

Comment: If it's not working correctly, it's because your question does not say anything about how you decide which line goes with which line. Please provide enough details in the question to answer it.

Comment: @ALT I think I guessed what you meant, check my edit and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment that's now gone, you said the correspondence between the two lists is by line number, so I'm assuming that in this answer.

If what you're trying to do is just insert the line from text2 between the two elements on the line from text1, then the solution below will work.

I suspect your actual need may be slightly different, but this should give you what you need to solve your issue.

```
text1 = """French,01
Brasil,07
USA,23
England,34
Egypt,51"""

text2 = """French
Paris
England
London"""

list1 = [line.split(",") for line in text1.split("\n")]
list2 = text2.split("\n")

for line1, line2 in zip(list1, list2):
    newline = [line1[0], line2, line1[1]]
    print(",".join(newline))
```

It's basically just a matter of parsing and wrangling the data into the structure you need, there's not much magic to it.

##### Another possible answer

I just had a thought, maybe your second file is meant to have the key on one line, and the value to use on the next one, alternating?

If so, try this:

```
list1 = [line.split(",") for line in text1.split("\n")]
list2 = text2.split("\n")
dict2 = dict(zip(list2[::2], list2[1::2]))
for line1 in list1:
    mapped_first_field = dict2.get(line1[0], "key_not_found")
    newline = [line1[0], mapped_first_field, line1[1]]
    print(",".join(newline))
```

Here the key logic is that `dict(zip(list2[::2], list2[1::2]))` builds a dict where the keys are the first, third, etc. line in text2, and the values in each case are from the subsequent line: the slice `list2[::2]` picks out elements indexed 0, 2, ..., and the slice `list2[1::2]` picks out elements indexed 1, 3, ...

Comment: for example i need french,paris,01
but the code prints as French,French,01

Comment: actually it works partially correctly, for example, the england part is correct.
`French,French,01
Brasil,Paris,07
USA,England,23
England,London,34
Egypt,...,51`

Comment: OK, now you're not asking for data manipulation. You're asking for artificial intelligence, to recognize that line 1 goes with line 2 (because French is spoken in Paris, maybe?). If you don't provide the logic you want used to match the lines, how can anyone help your with your problem? If your two texts are not actually aligned line by line, fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine the two like this to create one common list and then do whatever you want with it

```
list1 = ['French','01', 'Brasil','07']
 list2 = ['French','Paris','England','London']
 for element in list1 :
    if element not in list2:
        list2.append(element)
    else:
        print(f"{element} is already in liste 2")
        print("liste2 : ")
        print(list2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

```py
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:

    city_records = (line for line in file2.read().splitlines())

    cities = {
        country: city
        for country, city in zip_longest(city_records, city_records)
    }
    
    result = [
        [country, cities.get(country), *other_columns]
        for country, *other_columns in csv.reader(file1)
    ]
```

Note: `city_records` must be a generator object, hence the generator comprehension.

---

Here is an executable example using [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to simulate the files:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO
from itertools import zip_longest
from pprint import pprint

content1 = """French,01
Brasil,07
USA,23
England,34
Egypt,51"""

content2 = """French
Paris
England
London"""

with StringIO(content1) as file1, StringIO(content2) as file2:
    
    city_records = (line for line in file2.read().splitlines())

    cities = {
        country: city
        for country, city in zip_longest(city_records, city_records)
    }
        
    result = [
        [country, cities.get(country), *other_columns]
        for country, *other_columns in csv.reader(file1)
    ]
    
    pprint(result)
```

Output:

```py
[['French', 'Paris', '01'],
 ['Brasil', None, '07'],
 ['USA', None, '23'],
 ['England', 'London', '34'],
 ['Egypt', None, '51']]
```